# Uniqueness of solutions of a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Cauchy problem

$$\begin{cases}y'(x)=\sqrt{y(x)}\\ y(0)=0\end{cases}$$

Clearly $y'(x)=\sqrt{y(x)}$ is a differential equation that can be solved with the separation of the variables, in fact:

$y'(x)=a(x)b(y(x))$

where $a(x)=1$ is continuous on $I=\mathbb{R}$, while $b(y(x))=\sqrt{y(x)}$ is continuous on $J=[0,+\infty)$, but it's not a lipschitzian function in a neighborhood of $0.$.. I can't use Picard–Lindelöf theorem. The uniqueness is not guaranteed.

Now the question: can I use the separation of variables, if I can't find a neighborhood of $0$ such that $b(y)\ne 0$?

Comment: Maybe your are involving too much theory.  Hint: just write $\frac{dy}{\sqrt(y)} = dx$ and integrate. Yoy get a constant of integration which you can determine by the initial condition.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze : wait, I know how to solve the differential equation. $$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{y'(t)}{\sqrt{y(t)}}dt=\int_{0}^{x}1dt$$
The problem here is that the first is an improper integral (right?)

Comment: @ Ixion Use separation of variables and write $$\int_0^y \frac{1}{\sqrt(y)}\,dy = \int_0^x \,dx$$ Here the integrals are indefinite. The $y$-integral is not improper as the inverse square root is integrable.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking but I would like to point out that $y=x^{2}/4$ and $y=0$ are two valid solutions of the IVP on $[0,\infty)$. So the solution is not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such Cauchy problem has infinite solutions: for any $c\geq 0$
$$y_{c}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & 0\leq x < c, \\
                          \frac{(x-c)^2}{4} & x \ge c.
  \end{cases}$$
is a solution. By separation of variables we get
$$\int\frac{y'(t)}{\sqrt{y(x)}}dx=\int 1dx \implies y(x)=\frac{(x-c)^2}{4}$$
which is valid as soon as $y(x)>0$ that is, $x\in [c,+\infty)$ when $c>0$. Such solution can be extended to $[0,c]$ by letting $y(x)=0$. Note that the extended solution is $C^1$ in $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Perfect, but, how can I find this kind of solution? Can I use the separation of variables?

Comment: Yes, for example  the case $x_0=0$ can be obtained  by solving the Cauchy problem $y(2)=1$.

Comment: So... I have to use the solution $\bar{y}(x)$ of $$\begin{cases}y'(x)=\sqrt{y(x)}\\ y(2)=1\end{cases}$$ and build the function:

$$\tilde{y}(x)=\begin{cases}\bar{y}(x)&\mbox{if}\ x\ge 0\\ 0&\mbox{if} \ x<0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, it's clear now! Thank you!